# oledb connection string not initialized

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, oledb

```
    namespace PCMS
    {
     public partial class frmPlayerInterface : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
        private DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public frmPlayerInterface(string getUser)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Projects\SDP\PCMS\SDP.accdb";
        lblUser.Text = getUser;
    }

    private void btnEnquire_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmEnquire frmenq = new frmEnquire();
        frmenq.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void btnTopUp1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmTopUp frmTU = new frmTopUp();
        frmTU.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void frmPlayerInterface_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();

        String sql = "select Balance from PlayerAccount where Player_User=@user";
        comm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("user", lblUser.Text));
        comm.CommandText = sql;

        OleDbDataReader cursor = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (cursor.Read())
        {

            lblBalance.Text = cursor["Balance"].ToString();
        }
        con.Close();



    }





}
```

}

Hey sorry guys asking this again but ive been trying this for the past three hours and wave the white flag. Still getting the same error.

I just want to have the selected balance value from the database to be shown in the label.

Thanks ><

Comment: Don't know if it's still true, but once upon a time setting the `CommandText` property cleared the `Parameters` collection. You needed to always set CommandText **before** adding parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not associating the connection with the command object:

```
    con.Open();
    String sql = "select Balance from PlayerAccount where Player_User=@user";
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
```

Note that reusing a connection is not always the best design.  Connections are pooled in .NET, so recreating them is generally not an expensive operation.  A better design would be to store the *connection string* as a class property then just create a connection when you need it:

```
private string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Projects\SDP\PCMS\SDP.accdb";  
// or better yet - pull form app.config...
```

and when you use it:

```
String sql = "select Balance from PlayerAccount where Player_User=@user";
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using(OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(sql, con))
    {
        ... Add parameters, execute query, return results
    }
}
```

Comment: @D Stanley  You are a life saver! and will try to keep all those stuff in mind. thanks!